# Как переустановить Java (32 бита) на Windows 7?

Tags: windows, java

Случайно удалил папку java и от неё на панели управления остался нерабочий значок. Когда я пытаюсь переустановить java, выходит сообщение с вопросом о переустановке, начинается удаление и оно не удается с надписью Error, ведь самой java нет. Как удалить этот значок с панели управления? Мне срочна нужна рабочая java.

Comment: "случайно удалил"

Comment: Увы, никаких файлов Javы вообще нет. Я даже в реестре удалил все о Javе. Думал переустановлю все заново. Запускаю Java инсталлятор, что то вроде начинает ставиться, а потом тут же ошибка вылетает: Error 25025. И дальше ее описание, типа предыдущее удаление Javы небыло завершено, нужно перезагрузить ПК перед установкой. Хотя ни единого файла Javы вообще нет на компе. Пробовал это делать - не помогло.

Comment: Все естественно делал как админ.

Comment: если есть точки восстановления в системе, попробуйте откатиться

Answer (score 2):

А запустить инсталлятор заново пробовали?

Удалите все папки с Java и запустите заново инсталлятор. От имени админа только все делайте (так надежнее).

Answer (score 0):

Удалите все, что связано с JDK, только JRE не трогайте. Потом поставьте заново. И будет вам счастье.

Comment: я таких файлов не нахожу(((


Answer (score 0):

Все есть на официальном сайте - [Java Uninstall Tool](https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp).
Затем переустановите Java заново.